# Google script change events queuing

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, onchange

I have set up a change event trigger on my google spreadsheet. This works well, except when several users access the sheet simultaneously. I have noticed some data corruption (rows overwritten).

Is there a way to make sure that some code triggered from a change event has to wait for code triggered from a prior change event to complete?

Comment: Use a lock, i.e. `LockService`

Comment: Thanks. That seems to do the trick.
I followed the examples in the google documentation: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock/lock#tryLock(Integer)
And the implementation turns out to be quite simple